# Problem in referring to figures

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I'm preparing a paper for submission to a journal. The journal submission system (Elsevier) requires me to load the EPS files (I convert my figures to EPS using gnuplot) separately. But if I do not include my figures in my `.tex` file how can I refer to my figures in LaTeX? Should I include my figures both in my paper and also load them separately? I wonder whether there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: Yes, including them in the document and uploaded them separately is one way to do it. I will upload a journal soon (TCAS-I) and this is how they told me to do it.

Comment: If you use the `\includegraphics` command, there is no problem at all. You refer to the file name of the image and the file is aside the tex document.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of including images in separate files is with the help of the `\includegraphics` command. You can use the general float for images as this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{myimage.eps}
\caption{caption of the image}
\label{fig:figure_reference_label}
\end{figure}
```

When you want to refer to that image you can use the `\ref{fig:figure_reference_label}` command in the body of text.

This implies that the images are in the same *folder* as the .tex document. But you can use relative paths to address the images, as in

```
\includegraphics{images/myimage.eps}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Don't forget to put `\usepackage{graphicx}` somewhere before `\begin{document}`